# If the activity of a solid is one why does adding salt to water increase the salt ion concentration?

Tags: equilibrium

Suppose salt dissolves in water according to the equation NaCl(s) -> Na(aq) + Cl(aq).  Since the activity of solid salt is 1, adding salt shouldn't affect sodium and chloride ions at equilibrium.  However, if I were to add salt to an unsaturated solution, the salt would dissolve and increase the ion concentrations.  How is it possible for the activity of solid salt to be 1 if it affects equilibrium in this way?  My only theory is that an unsaturated solution is not at equilibrium, but I'm not sure this is correct.

Comment: The activity of a solid stuff is 1, and it is independent on the presence of any more or less concentrated solution.

Comment: A system of unsaturated solution **and** solid salt is indeed out of equilibrium.

Comment: Salt always dissolves, no matter if the solution is saturated or not. When the solution is saturated, however, the rate of salt dissolving and salt precipitating is equal, so the concentration does not change anymore. In fact, when you add salt to a saturated solution, the rate of dissolution goes up, as does the rate of precipitation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct: an unsaturated solution is not in equilibrium. Equilibrium is the state when rate of dissolution is equal to rate of crystallisation. But in an unsaturated solution there is only dissolution of salt in the water and no crystallisation back to salt.

Comment: Not exactly. Dissolution is just faster than crystallisation,leading to the net dissolution.

Comment: That is too ideal for a practical idea like this. Going by idealism like this couldn't it also be said that activity of liquids is not unity.

Comment: You may forget about 2 principal things. 1/ Equilibriums are on molecular level dynamic, not static. There are always the opposite processes, that just at equilibrium happen ongoing at the same rate.2/ molecules have no clue if the system is in equilibrium or not. There are no traffic lights saying now you may  dissolve, or now you may crystallize. Similarly, the thermal energy goes always from colder to warmer object as well. Just at lower rater then in the opposite direction.